# How to use the URL filepath as parameters in plain html/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, url, web-applications, get

I know about setting and getting URL parameters, e.g. `example.com/index.html?x=foo&y=bar&z=hello` would give your javascript access to the `x`, `y`, and `z` variables specified in the URL.

What I wish for is the same behavior but utilizing the file path part of the URL. E.g. `example.com/index.html/foo/bar/hello`.

How can I accomplish this? In particular,

1. How can I make sure the browser knows to go to `index.html` even though the file path `index.html/foo/bar/hello` was specified?
2. How can I update the URL to `example.com/index.html/foo/bar/world`, such that if I press "Back" on the browser, it will go back to `example.com/index.html/foo/bar/hello`.

Furthermore, I'd heavily prefer if the solution was in pure javascript/html, without reliance on jquery or any other libraries.

Comment: But `/foo/bar/hello.` should be a file to access it.

Comment: Would probably make more sense if the path after `index.html` was a url hash value .... `example.com/index.html#/foo/bar/hello`. Server would only know `index.html` and your front end could parse the hash to do whatever is needed from `location.hash`

Comment: Alternative is you need server side to manage sending the index.html when those other path parts exist. Not known what stack you use on server

Comment: This is something that can only be done server-side

Comment: So I've found that [History.pushstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) can accomplish this with `window.history.pushState({x: "foo", y: "bar", z: "hello"}, "", "/foo/bar/hello")`, with navigation working fine and everything. The only thing is that directly entering the url `example.com/index.html/foo/bar/hello` won't work properly. You're saying the only way the URL could work properly is messing with the server side, then?

Comment: If you don't use url hash then yes the server must handle the irregular url when entered directly in address bar or from external link. Note that in early days of single page apps the hash was used heavily to avoid the server side issues you are needing to circumvent

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 scenarios you should handle.

1. What if the user is on a foreign page and wants to visit your page using the link example.com/index.html/foo/bar? This should be handled on the server not on the client side.
2. If the user is already on some page, say example.com/index.html and wants to go to example.com/index.html/foo/bar, you may use the pushState method. You may look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState to change the current URL & and this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate to do something when the user presses the back button.